# iPhone Table Background Color Problem

Tags: iphone, colors, background

I have these two lines of code:

Line 1:
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:((float) 102.0f)                                          green:((float) 204.0f)                                                           blue:((float) 255.0f)                                                      alpha:1.0f];

Line 2:
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

Line 1 does not change background, however, line two does!  What's going on here?  Please tell me :(

Answer (score 4):

try doing this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.533 green:0.670 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: To clarify: the range of the component values is 0.0-1.0.  Not 0.0-255.0